# Override Kaminari configuration in Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines, kaminari

I am currently trying to fix a problem in my engine:
I am providing a logging engine with back-end views so that I need a pagination.
Since kaminari and will_paginate are cockblocking each other I am running in problems.

So I need a way to configure Kaminari params to override the method name directly in my engine.

Kaminari is on version `0.14.1` and loaded as dependency in the `.gemspec`.
If I call it directly through an initilizer in the engines `config/initializers/kaminari_config.rb` file with

`Kaminari.configure do |config|`

I get:

`uninitialized constant Kaminari`

I would love to hear your solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this line to your file:

> require 'kaminari'

To load the module, otherwise ruby don't recognise it.

Comment: undefined method 'import;'